# Embeded query inside select : Postgres query optimizer vs other databases

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a performance problem when I execute this query on PostgresDB :

```
SELECT u.login "Login", 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM journal_acces j
      WHERE u.login = j.login)
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END "IsUtilise"
  FROM utilisateur u
```

Table `utilisateur` have 1K records, and table `journal_acces` have 50K records.
When I execute it in Postgres, it takes around 25 seconds to execute (Which is huge)

I tried to execute the exact same query on SqlServer express, MySql, and Oracle express (Same data, same machine), and they all execute the query nearly instantaneously (~ 0.1 sec).

This is the execution plan for Postgres :

```
    Seq Scan on public.utilisateur u  (cost=0.00..372.40 rows=1017 width=17) (actual time=0.057..11.159 rows=1017 loops=1)
  Output: u.login, CASE WHEN (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  Buffers: shared hit=2060
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Index Only Scan using journalacces_utilisateur_fk on public.journal_acces j  (cost=0.29..131.48 rows=3154 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1017)
          Index Cond: (j.login_utilisateur = (u.login)::text)
          Heap Fetches: 0
          Buffers: shared hit=2035
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Index Only Scan using journalacces_utilisateur_fk on public.journal_acces j_1  (cost=0.29..1837.87 rows=50000 width=32) (never executed)
          Output: j_1.login_utilisateur
          Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.366 ms
Execution Time: 11.555 ms
```

[image]
[image]

And this is the execution plan for Mysql :
[image]

Is Postgres that bad for optimizing this kind of query (embedded select having filter on the outer query) ? or can I tune it so it will behave same as the other databases ?

**Note** : I tried to rewrite the query with a join, and it takes 0.3 sec to run (which is good and is similar to the other DB), but I have a limitation on my application and I cannot use the join version of it.

Comment: I can't reproduce that at all.  What version of PostgreSQL are you using?  What non-default settings do you have?  Do you have any indexes?

Comment: Postgres V12 on Windows.
I use the default settings, no customization.
I have an index in table journal_acces on column login.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it on that version and platform.  It either uses the index, or a hashed subplan, and either way is quite fast.  Can you repeat the query with `explain (analyze,buffers,verbose)` and post that as formatted text (not images)?

Comment: Also, what are your column types?  Do you have a full reproducer case (CREATE for tables and indices, population with random/dummy data, vac/analyze, etc.)

Comment: This is a dump of the database : https://github.com/iheb719/postgresbdperf

Comment: I also added the explain result as formatted text

Comment: The query takes 11 **milli**seconds, which is 0.011 seconds - not 25 seconds.

Comment: Your query doesn't work with your dump, it results in "*column j.login does not exist*" and indeed the table `journal_acces` does not have a column `login`. Did you mean to use `j.login_utilisateur`

Comment: Btw: this is the plan that Postgres 14 uses: https://explain.depesz.com/s/7JqQ - seems to be slightly better

Comment: Yes its login_utilisateur sry for that. Its really weird. I will try installing Postgres14 on a new machine and test it again. Maybe there is something corrupted with my postgres installation !

Comment: Based on the new plan you posted, there is no problem.  If the problem suddenly fixed itself that doesn't sound like corruption, but like a problem with stats which was later fixed by autovacuum doing an analyze.